# How to avoid print outs when running Weka from command line

Tags: weka

I am running Weka from my command line, whether building a model or re-evaluating one and I would like to not see the model/predictions print out on the screen.
I've searched this topic numerous times and haven't found an answer.  Anyone here know how to do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

`weka` is send that information to the terminal through either `stdout` or `stderr`. In a bash shell (and probably other POSIX shells, but I don't know), you can append `> /dev/null` and/or `2> /dev/null` to send the `stdout` and/or `stderr` streams to a black hole. If your OS doesn't have /dev/null set up, then you could create whatever meaningless temporary file you want. It will never be very large, and will be overwritten every time you run the command.